# How i can export the action to two differents pages from submit button?

Tags: php, html, forms, button, submit

this is some stupid but i dont know.
How i can export the action to two differents sections from submit button?
I want the cancel button to take me to one page and the accept button to take me to another. How can I apply a conditional that takes different actions?

My buttons are Accept and Cancel...

```
<section>
      <form action="/news">
           <input type="submit" id="button" value="Accept"> <input type="submit" class="button2" value="Cancel">
      </form>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `export the action`?

Comment: I want the cancel button to take me to one page and the accept button to take me to another. How can I apply a conditional that takes different actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="submit.html">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <button type="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
            <button type="cancel" formaction="cancel.html">cancel</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically with html you can make different action in form like this